# Cannot reach most internet pages

Tags: internet, dns, systemd, systemd-resolved

I have to type this using my phone. This morning my computer was working fine, for some reason I cannot access most pages anymore. Facebook and Google works, askubuntu.com and most other pages doesn't.
I tried to use the [Google DNS server](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/), but it does not help. The problem occurs with Firefox and Chrome. I am using the same Wi-Fi with my phone, without a problem. I use Ubuntu 16.04.

I realized that 'facebook.com' can be resolved, 'askubuntu.com' can't. The error says:

```
$ systemd-resolve askubuntu.com
askubuntu.com: resolve call failed: 'askubuntu.com' does not have any RR of the requested type
```

The server given in `/etc/resolve.conf` is 127.0.1.1 and can be reached by ping.

Comment: Have you rebooted the computer yet? That might fix it.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't help. I also tried to empty the cache.

Comment: Are you connecting wireless, or wired? Do you have cable or DSL?

Comment: Wifi, the same problem account by connectiin with ethernet. Cable internet.

Comment: Have you rebooted/restarted your router, cable modem, and hubs/switches? Is your MTU = 1500?

Comment: Wow. That solved the problem. The first time accessing a page took forever, but now it's fine. How did that help? I mean, it worked for the phone, so I checked for problems with the computer.

Comment: BTW: The file is `/etc/resolv.conf` (not resolve.conf).

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/987136/edit) your question adding the output of `systemd-resolve --status` and the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/hosts`?